# Grid columns and rows set dynamically with javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to build a grid-layout like this:

| a | c | f |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | d | g |
|  | e | h |

These grid-items would be generated from the following array:

```
const options: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
```

Right now i have the following snippet

```
let gridColumnStart = 2;

const optionItems = options.map((option, idx) => {

    if (idx > 1 && idx % 4 === 1) {
      gridColumnStart++;
    }

    return (
     <div style={
          idx > 1
            ? { gridColumn: gridColumnStart, gridRow:  }
            : undefined
        }
     >{option}</div>
    )
});

<div style={display:grid}>{optionItems}</div>
```

So far i got the columns right, but i can't seem to figure out the rows...
Items with index 2,3,4 should have gridRowValues of 1,2,3
Again items with index 5,6,7 should have gridRowValues of 1,2,3
The applied styles should be looking something like this:

```
<div> a </div>
<div> b </div>
<div style={ gridRow: 1, gridColumn: 2}> c </div>
<div style={ gridRow: 2, gridColumn: 2}> d </div>
<div style={ gridRow: 3, gridColumn: 2}> e </div>
<div style={ gridRow: 1, gridColumn: 3}> f </div>
<div style={ gridRow: 2, gridColumn: 3}> g </div>
<div style={ gridRow: 3, gridColumn: 3}> h </div>
```

Any suggestion? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compute the grid row/col by solely the index of the current cell:

```js
const gridRow = ((idx - gridColStart) % gridCols) + 1;
const gridColumn = Math.floor((idx - gridColStart) / gridCols) + gridColStart;
```

You can adapt the code below into your React component.

```js
const options = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];
const grid = document.querySelector('.my-grid');
const gridColStart = 2;
const gridCols = 3;

options.forEach((option, idx) => {
  const cell = document.createElement('div');
  const gridRow = ((idx - gridColStart) % gridCols) + 1;
  const gridColumn = Math.floor((idx - gridColStart) / gridCols) + gridColStart;
  
  cell.classList.add('cell');
  
  if (idx > gridColStart - 1) {
    if (gridRow) { cell.style.gridRow = gridRow; }
    if (gridColumn) { cell.style.gridColumn = gridColumn; }
  }
  
  if (gridRow === 1 || gridRow === -1) {
    cell.classList.add('cell-header');
  }
  
  cell.textContent = option;

  grid.appendChild(cell);
});
```

```css
body {
  background: #000;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: smaller;
}

.my-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1px;
  background: #222;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}

.cell {
  padding: 0.5em;
  color: #FFF;
  outline: 1px solid #AAA;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.cell-header {
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-grid"></div>
```